# sql server management studio 2017 (v.17.8.1) - how to open multiple .sql files at once in same instance

Tags: sql, ssms

I would like to be able to multi-select stored procedures in SSMS then right click > open and have all the selected files open in different tabs of the same SSMS window.

Looking online I can find references to [opening via Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123365/how-to-open-multiple-sql-files-in-only-one-ssms-instance), which I don't want, and looks like still one at a time by double-clicking on each file. I can't actually find anything that details how to do this in SSMS and have all files open at once. To be honest, I can't even see how to multi-select files (within object explorer).

I hope this doesn't come across as too broad but my Google-fu is failing me.

Full set-up:

```
| Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   | 14.0.17277.0    |
| Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools | 14.0.1016.262   |
| Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  | 10.0.17763.1    |
| Microsoft MSXML                          | 3.0 6.0         |
| Microsoft Internet Explorer              | 9.11.17763.0    |
| Microsoft .NET Framework                 | 4.0.30319.42000 |
| Operating System                         | 6.3.17763       |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop multiple SQL files into SSMS. You may also File > Open > File and select multiple files with CTRL or SHIFT trick.